# Dissimilarity Matrix by appending several outputs from a function

Tags: j

```
v=: ((1 2);(3 4);(0 5);(2 1))
diff=: ([{]) ,. ]
direction_vector=: <"1 @: (-"0 @:(-/"2 @: (>"0 @: (diff))))
distance=: +/"1 @: *: @: (>"2 @:(direction_vector))
```

I want to get a dissimilarity matrix that looks like

```
(0 distance v),. (1 distance v),. (2 distance v) ,. (3 distance v)
```

I tried

```
i.4 distance v
```

which gave me an index error

Anyone can help me on this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are close, but you have two issues to deal with. One is that you want to complete the calculation of `i. 4` before you apply distance (which is why you get the index error). Parenthesis to change the order of calculation are the solution to this.

```
   i. 4 distance v
|index error: diff
|   i.4     distance v
   (i. 4) distance v
0 0 0 0
```

The second issue is that you want to apply each atom of `i.4` to the whole of `v` and you do this by using `"` (rank) to specify `0` (atoms) for the left argument and `_` (infinity) for the whole of the right argument.

```
   (i. 4) distance"0 _ v
 0  8 10  2
 8  0 10 10
10 10  0 20
 2 10 20  0
```